# "Loading" icon during Flex Mobile HTTPService

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, loading, busyindicator

Is there any way to display some sort of "loading" sign or icon during a HTTPService call in Flex Mobile? Something like showBusyCursor in regular flex?

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check out the BusyIndicator component (exclusive to mobile).